# Is there a way to limit computer time for a child on Big Sur?

Tags: parental-controls

One of the things that I always mentioned to people with children in the past is that macOS was great about limiting screen time through the Parental Controls preference applet. For example, you could set that child's account was limited to 1 hour a day and when that time limit was reached, the computer would give them a warning before locking them out and requiring an administrator password to get additional time. This has worked great for us.

With Big Sur, it looks like the Parental Controls pref has been removed altogether in favor of the "Screen Time" applet. While it does allow for individual application time limits, it doesn't seem to support any kind of "password required to extend" feature nor does it prevent them from getting into the computer.

Has the feature of locking someone out after a certainly daily time limit been removed? Is there a way of doing this now on Big Sur? I find it hard to believe that Apple removed this feature but I'm not having any luck getting any limits enforced; when something does pop up (individual app limit), the user can simply press "extend limit" without any password or other restrictions.

Please tell me there is still a way to do this incredibly useful feature that has been there for over a decade!

Comment: There is controls in the Screen Time setting System Preferences. You can set a pin code and set limits for screen time in this page (password setting is in the [Options] category)

Comment: The thing is, the Screen Time prefs doesn't seem to do the same thing as the older Parental Controls applet; what I'm looking for is limiting the amount of time that the account is allowed to be IN USE... the Screen Time mechanism still allows you to log in and use Finder, but then gets granular to each app which is annoying.